# Search for several patterns at the same time in a list of text files

Tags: text

I have a folder with text files, and want to search inside all the text files, if they have certain words at the same time, not necessarily in the same line. I've tried with `grep` but works line by line:

`file-1.txt`:

```
You shall find of the king a husband, madam; you,
sir, a father: he that so generally is at all times
good must of necessity hold his virtue to you; whose
worthiness would stir it up where it wanted rather
than lack it where there is such abundance.
```

`file-2.txt`:

```
He was excellent necessity, madam: the father very
lately spoke of him admiringly and mourningly: he
was skilful enough to have lived still, if knowledge
could be set up against mortality.
He hath abandoned his physicians, king; under whose
practises he hath persecuted time with hope, and
finds no other advantage in the process but only the
losing of hope by time.
```

I want to detect if `king` and `father` are present in the same file.
The code I've tried is:

```
for file in file-*.txt; do grep -E 'king.*father' "$file" && echo $file; done
```

But no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

A) grep -E still won't work across lines. Using -z will help, making all the file count as one line:

```
for file in file-*.txt; do grep -z  'king.*father' "$file" && echo $file; done
```

- This will match file-1.txt

B) Do I understand you'll need the words in different order too? For that you'll need egrep, and specifying both expressions inside a (), separated by a |:

```
for file in file-*.txt; do egrep -z  '(king.*father|father.*king)' "$file" && echo $file; done
```

Comment: Yes, of course then can be in any order. I guess it could be more difficult if there were say 5 words, you will have to do all the permutations. Or use `grep-q` on each term.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, @Technologeeks answer is on point:

```
for file in file-*.txt; do egrep -z  '(king.*father|father.*king)' "$file" && echo $file; done
```

However, to search for lots of words at the same time:

```
for file in file-*.txt; do grep -q 'king' "$file" && grep -q 'father' "$file" && grep -q 'freedom' "$file" && grep -q 'matter' "$file" && echo $file; done
```

Can be done also with `-z` on each grep. Also add `-q` on last one:

```
for file in file-*.txt; do cat "$file" | grep -z father | grep -z king | grep -z -q time && echo "$file" ; done
```

Comment: Chaining separate grep like this is *incredibly* wasteful because it causes a *lot* of processes to spawn. You're much better off with egrep and then (freedom|matter|father|king). If you want ALL five words to appear, in any order, that's actually easier - and then chaining is the way to go -  grep '1stword' $file | grep '2ndword' | grep '3rdword' - because that would only have the last | grep succeed if all others before it have been matched

Comment: That command filters lines, so unless all five are in the same line will fail. It has to be the five in same file, not same line.

Comment: if you use -z in all of them then the entire file counts as a single line. Then it doesn't fail. It's all in the arguments..